# Launching multiple browser url in groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins pipeline,

I was launch multiple URL in side groovy script, like as below

```
   stages {
    stage("Launch URL") {
        steps {
            script {

            def url1 = "https://www.paypal.com/us/home".toURL().getText()
            def url2 = "https://www.ebay.com".toURL().getText()
            def url3 = "https://www.yahoo.com/".toURL().getText()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this one.
Is it possible to use one variable and execute all three urls?

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? You should also be careful to use `getText()` and other Groovy methods due to how Jenkins pipelines execute.

Comment: I mean, instead of using three variables like url1, url2, url3, is there a way to use one variable and execute all three url's.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner part of your code, you can do the following in groovy:

```
def texts = ["https://www.paypal.com/us/home",
             "https://www.ebay.com",
             "https://www.yahoo.com/".collect { 
  it.toURL().text
}
```

where texts will be a `List<String>` containing the string content returned from each url respectively.